# How execute partial Update after render view?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I don't know if this is a bug...
But I insert into AfterRestoreView event of my Xpages

```
view.postScript("RefreshActionBar('')");
```

Into the function Javascript RefreshActionBar I insert this code:

```
alert("before")
XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:divActBar}",{}); 
alert("after")
```

Seem that the code work (show the alert messages...but the XSP.partialRefreshGet() dont' execute.. (With firebug I don't see GET)

Is normal?

Comment: There is a Delay between all Partial Refreshs. Try to call *XSP.allowSubmit()* before the partial refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. This worked for me. :)

```
 XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:divActBar}", {
    onComplete: function() {
        //
    }
}
```